# xrdp is not connecting to SLES11 SP4

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, sles, xrdp

I have a SLES11 SP4 machine available with me. I have installed xrdp using zypper.
The command I used to install was `zypper in xrdp` and followed on-console messages.

xrdp installed successfully. But when I tried to connect from Windows 7 machine it said the machine is not up. I tried to start xrdp by typing command `xrdp`, it started and said xrdp started and gave a pid. Now connecting through windows was leading to login. I entered the credentials and it went into forever connecting mode.

Tried stopping xrdp by `xrdp -kill` and restarting again. But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fair amount of research regarding this issue. I could find that just executing command `xrdp` doesn't work. The xrdp should be started with the system's own service startup mechanism.

For ex.

in SLES11 machines, use command `/etc/init.d/xrdp start`
in SLES12 machines, use command `systemctl start xrdp`

Similarly use the native system service management to startup and shutdown xrdp. Since my machine is SLES11 I used the above command and it worked.

Before executing that, we have to kill all the xrdp processes, restart the machine and start the xrdp using above commands.